# program went into dead lock using condition variable in c++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, condition-variable

I am currently trying to learn how to use a `condition_variable` for thread synchronization. For testing, I have made the demo application shown below. When I start it, it runs into a dead lock. I know the location where this happens, but I'm unable to understand *why* the deadlock occurs.

I know that a `condition_variable`'s `wait` function will automatically unlock the mutex when the condition is not true, so the main thread should not be blocked in the second pass. But it is just this what happens.

Could anybody explain why?

```
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

bool flag = false;
std::mutex g_mutex;
std::condition_variable cv;


void threadProc()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(g_mutex);

    while (true)
    {
        static int count = 0;

        std::cout << "wait for flag" << ++count << std::endl;

        cv.wait(lck, []() {return flag; }); // !!!It will blocked at the second round

        std::cout << "flag is true " << count << std::endl;

        flag = false;
        lck.unlock();
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::thread t(threadProc);

    while (true)
    {
        static int count = 0;

        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(g_mutex); // !!!It will blocked at the second round

            flag = true;
            std::cout << "set flag " << ++count << std::endl;
        }

        cv.notify_one();

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }


    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hmm, it's not just locks , it crashes for me at that point

Comment: yes, My build env is VS2017. then i try it in clang, it crashes and promote that unlock a mutex which in a unlocked state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the problem by moving the unique_lock(...) statement inside the while loop. As it is now, you're attempting to unlock lck on round 2 but it was not in a locked state, since, after round 1 you never locked it again.

Comment: Thanks. you mean when cv.wait on round 2, cv.wait found the condition is false,  then cv.wait try to unlock lck, but lck itself in a unlocked state, then it blocked or some kind crashed.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that a condition_variable's wait function will automatically unlock the mutex when the condition is not true.

Um..., yes..., Just to be absolutely clear, `cv.wait(lck, f)` does this:

```
while(! f()) {
    cv.wait(lck);
}
```

And each call to `cv.wait(lck)` will;

- unlock `lck`,
- wait until some other thread calls `cv.notify_one()` or `cv.notify_all()`,
- re-lock `lck`, and then
- return.

Comment: Thanks. another question, if it unlock the lck in step 1, how it can assure that the wait function in step2 will take effect before a notification form other thread?